# I want to break a .SP1 navigation file into individual files based on the 2d Seismic Line names (col 1) in the compiled .SP1 file

Tags: fme-form

I received a .SP1 (navigation text type file) from Seismic Exchange and I need to break up that file into individual .SP1 files based on the 2D line names (col 1) and the associated row data preserved as is, while ignoring the header H-01-H20 data.  I just got FME Desktop and thought maybe I could use that the read the file, use a transform function to split and then write new files into a destination folder in a automated fashion.  I've been doing this manually which and when you have dozens of 2D lines it can take some time and introduce error.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe the SEG-P1 reader can read that format and create fme geometry https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-ReadersWriters/seg-p1/seg-p1.htm (a sample .sp1 would be needed to confirm).